# how to resolve the error "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, stored-procedures

Hello I am doing a job for the school and I used asp.net mvc to create the page and make the connection to the database. But when I insert an error "An item with the same key has already been added". I checked my tables and my procedures and the variable "ID" increases.
And if inserting in the database there is no error. Anyone who can help me?
Thank you to anyone who wasted their time helping me.Thanks.

> Class TransController, 
>   method executed after the Create button on the web page is pressed

```
 [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Titulo,Data,Imagem,Descricao,Tipo")] Transmontanos TM)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (Request.Files != null && Request.Files[0] != null)
            {
                var fileName = Request.Files[0].FileName;
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Images/"), fileName);
                Request.Files[0].SaveAs(path);

                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                var img = Image.FromFile(path);
                img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

                TM.Imagem = ms.ToArray();
            }

            Services.AddObject(TM);

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(TM);
    }
```

> Class Services

```
 public static void AddObject(Transmontanos TM)
    {
        using (var db = new TransmontanosEntities())
        {
           var result= db.GetType(TM.Tipo).FirstOrDefault();

            db.Add_object(TM.Titulo, TM.Data, TM.Imagem, TM.Descricao, result.ID);

        }
    }
```

> Database (Table
>   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpwhM.png) ; Stored Procedure Add_object
>   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzxwQ.png) )
>
> Structure of my project
>   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLtvq.png)
>
> Error
>   [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NYbmU.png)

Comment: The error says duplicated key in Dictionary, not DB table. Do you use Dictionary anywhere?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe hello, I don't use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please check this:
1-what is this `result.ID` insert ? it could bring old id and try to insert it.
2-do you specify the ID column as Key in c# and Primary Key in SQL.
3-please use this method i use to add the ID manually in DB because auto increment some time fail
`SELECT  @ID = ISNULL(MAX(ID), 0) + 1
    FROM #YourTable`

hope this helpfull